# Redirect from one Area's action to a action in the "root"-area?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use the latest version of ASP.Net MVC 2 RC.

My question is, how do I redirect from one action that's in the "Blog"-area to the index-action in the home-controller that exists in the "root" of my application (no area)?

I tried:

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
```

but this redirects to **/Blog/home**, where Blog is the name of my Area.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "home", new { area = "" });
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However, the ViewData seems to get lost :S I'll use Sessions instead :)

Answer (score 5):

If using the default routing this should work too, not sure what happens to the ViewData.

```
return Redirect("~/");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but I didn't downvote because it might do for someone else.